# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'map'

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, arcpy

I am having trouble getting this code to run and I am getting the following error:

```
strucArray = np.array(arrayTuple, np.dtype([('inSeqNum', np.int), (lstVals[0], np.float)]))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'map'
```

This is the block of code:

```
seqnum = None
lstFile = open(inListFileName)

for lstLn in lstFile.readlines():
    lstVals = lstLn.strip().split()

    basePath=os.getcwd()
    file=os.path.join(basePath, 'OUT_ST',lstVals[1])

    if len(lstVals) > 1:
        loadArray = np.loadtxt(file).flatten()

        if seqnum is None:
            seqnum = np.arange(1, len(loadArray) + 1)
    
        arrayTuple = map(tuple, np.column_stack((seqnum, loadArray)))
        
        strucArray = np.array(arrayTuple, np.dtype([('inSeqNum', np.int), (lstVals[0], np.float)]))
    
        arcpy.da.ExtendTable(target, seqFieldName, strucArray, 'inSeqNum', False)

lstFile.close()
```

Comment: In Python3 `map` doesn't evaluate its values; it just sets up a mapping.  `list(map...)` is required to actually perform the mapping.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to add a list casting to this line:

```
strucArray = np.array(arrayTuple, np.dtype([('inSeqNum', np.int), (lstVals[0], np.float)])
```

To this:

```
strucArray = np.array(list(arrayTuple), np.dtype([('inSeqNum', np.int)`, (lstVals[0], np.float)]))
```